# trying to check if string exist with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetchall

I'm trying to check if a string exist in my database. but i keep getting this error message "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object on line 8"

```
$string = random_string(30);

$sql = create_sql(); //returns a PDO object with connection to the database
$data = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM session WHERE string =:string");
$data->bindParam(':string', $string);
$data = $data->execute();

$row = $data->fetchAll();

if(empty($row)){
```

Comment: there is no fetch() in this code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: You are **overwriting** your $data variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses `fetchAll()`, but the bug is pretty obvious. `qwertynl`'s comment is correct -  you're overwriting `$data` so afterwards it's not a [`PDOStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object so you can't use the `fetch()` or `fetchAll()` methods.

Update your code to the following and you should be good to go.

```
$string = random_string(30);

$sql = create_sql(); //returns a PDO object with connection to the database
$stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM session WHERE string =:string");
$stmt->bindParam(':string', $string);
$stmt->execute();

$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thank you, voter. Much appreciated, and so were the grammar updates.